# Linkdatabase not working in CD Server

Tags: link-database

In Sitecore, I am referring one content item using multilist. While checking selected content item references in content editor **Navigate -> links** in CM it's showing all referring item. After published to web database, it's not displaying latest referred item. But, same functionality working fine in local system. In my code, I have used following snippet.

```
Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item)
```

After rebuild link database, it's working as expected. 
Please help how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you check the value of the settings LinkDatabase.UpdateDuringPublish ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber LinkDatabase.UpdateDuringPublish set to true

Comment: Does the CD Server makes use of the same Core DB as CM?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya: Yes we are using same core db for CM and CD.

Comment: Did you publish/republish both items?  Both referrer and referee

Comment: @Mark Cassidy: Referrer item newly created and published. But referee item is existing one. I didn't do publish. But after saw your query i did publish both the item but still reference link not updated in referee item.